# How secure is a header redirect? Can it be bypassed?

Tags: php, security, redirect, header, location

How secure are header redirects? As I understand it, the header information instructs the browser what to do. Therefore, if the header location is set to some other place, can the browser still be made to land on the initial page?

```
if(!$loggedin){
header('Location: someotherpage.php')
}
```

If someone, (cough cough) forgot to use an exit command after the header, could someone still land on that page?

Comment: You may find https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noredirect/ a useful addon for firefox. This will allow you to see what really is being sent. I've seen sites (that i have permission to test) that allow the entire admin interfaces can be used anonymously, because they redirect-without-exit to the login page.

Comment: Thank you Cheekysoft. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If someone, (cough cough) forgot to use an exit command after the header, could someone still land on that page?

Sure - rather than *land* on that page (which he already has), forgetting an `exit()` means the client can still *see* any data emitted after those lines. Nobody can *force* the client to leave immediately after receiving a `Location:` header. That action is entirely voluntary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely. That is why an else should follow(or an exit) after a redirect in the case that you want to avoid showing illegitimate information. If one uses a custom request, they can easily view what follows after a redirect request, it's a pretty standard security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It would be possible to still land on that page, you cannot force 'Location'. It's also possible to "accidentally" load the rest of the page if the page throws "headers already sent" errors. 
It is good practice to use `exit;` after sending a `header('Location...')`.

See PHP function: [headers_sent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php)